# Use 'default value' in table when NULL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am building a config table and want one row to be the default value. For example, I have a `list` table of all my databases and a table called `msg` which has all my return values. In the `msg` table, I have one row that is 'alldbs' and I want that value returned if there isn't another row for the joined database.

So the output should be:

```
--LIST TABLE
dbname                                             createdate
-------------------------------------------------- -----------------------
master                                             2015-06-23 10:05:14.363
model                                              2015-06-23 10:05:14.363
msdb                                               2015-06-23 10:05:14.363
tempdb                                             2015-06-23 10:05:14.363
dummy                                              2015-06-23 10:05:14.363

--MSG Table
dbname                                             msgval
-------------------------------------------------- --------------------
alldbs                                             Message 1
dummy                                              Message 2


--DESIRED OUTPUT
dbname                                             msgval
-------------------------------------------------- --------------------
dummy                                              Message 2
master                                             Message 1
model                                              Message 1
msdb                                               Message 1
tempdb                                             Message 1
```

Now I can get the result, but the query is clunky and it seems like there should be a better way:

```
select
    a.dbname
    ,b.msgval
from
    list a
    join msg b on a.dbname = b.dbname
union all
select
    a.dbname
    ,b.msgval
from
    list a
    ,msg b
where
    a.dbname not in (select dbname from msg)
    and b.dbname = 'alldbs'
```

Is there a more efficient way to write this query?

[SQLFiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6b69d/1/0) using SQL 2014.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using another `left join`:

```
select
    a.dbname
    , coalesce(b.msgval, d.msgval) as msgval
from
    list a
    left join msg b on a.dbname = b.dbname
    left join msg d on  b.dbname is null
                    and d.dbname = 'alldbs' ;
```

or a `cross` join (this requires an `'alldbs'` row to be present, otherwise it will return 0 results.):

```
select
    a.dbname
    , coalesce(b.msgval, d.msgval) as msgval
from
    msg d 
    cross join list a 
    left join msg b on a.dbname = b.dbname
where d.dbname = 'alldbs' ;
```

[SQlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6b69d/19)

Both queries assume there is only one row with `dbname = 'alldbs'`. If not, use the `apply` version provided by AndriyM.

Answer (score 7):

Another way (not as pretty looking to me after seeing @ypercube's suggestion, but still...):

```
SELECT
  l.dbname,
  x.msgval
FROM
  dbo.list AS l
  CROSS APPLY
    (
      SELECT TOP (1)
        m.msgval
      FROM
        dbo.msg AS m
      WHERE
        m.dbname IN (l.dbname, 'alldbs')
      ORDER BY
        CASE m.dbname WHEN 'alldbs' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END ASC
    ) AS x
;
```

Comment: While I accepted @ypercube's as the answer, this is query has the lowest logical reads.

Answer (score 5):

Using a subselect to get the missing msg:

```
select a.dbname
    ,  coalesce(b.msgval, (select msgval 
                           from msg c 
                           where dbname = 'alldbs')) as msgval 
from list a
left join msg b 
    on a.dbname = b.dbname
```